# Outlook 2010 search doesn't work

Tags: microsoft-outlook

We have a user just Migrated to Outlook 2010. Everything works find but the search function won't do search at all. I went to Control Panel, Indexing option, selected Microsoft, Modify and unchecked Microsoft Outlook then Checked it again to re-do the indexing. It doesn't work. Then I went to Control Panel, Indexing option, selected Microsoft, Advanced and Rebuilt but also doesn't work. I repaired the OST and it also doesn't work. After I unchecked "use cached mode", the search function works but after I check  "use cached mode" again, it doesn't work! I am having the user using his Outlook with "use cached mode" unchecked but is there a fix without using "use cached mode" unchecked

Comment: 1) Did you try renaming the ost file after outlook was closed? 2) is windows search started under services.msc

Comment: Are you searching for a word or a number? I had the situation once that I needed to search for `test1234` and I searched for 1234, which was not found (but `test1234` was, afterwards).

Answer (score 2):

Do the below settings and restart the outlook

Open Outlook click on File -> Options -> Search > Indexing options -> Modify -> Uncheck Outlook

Click on OK then close and restart Outlook to check if search results fetch correctly.

Comment: Don't forget to restart Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just love the changes? What I do is to: select the Inbox, press CTRL+SHIFT+F, choose "Browse ...", then check "Search subfolders". This is known as "Advanced Find".

Answer (score 0):

Did you try search in outlook safe mode?
Start > Type "outlook /safe" without quotes.

Also make sure "Indexing Service" and "Windows Search" is enabled in Turn Windows Features on or off.
Start > Control panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on or off